# What is the best map and team build to earn the Survival Onyx Medal in Gears of War Judgement?

Tags: gears-of-war-judgment

I have been playing **survival mode** with some [in my mind] decent players I met in Gears of War Judgement and we have been having some troubles trying to earn the Onyx Medal for the **Survival mode: Survive wave 10 on insane difficulty (any map)**. Seeing as there is no way ( to my knowledge ) to start the wave on 10 - we have spent hours trying to earn this... *sad panda*

We have been experimenting with many different team builds and maps and so far we have discovered one map that [we figured] would be the easiest due to the map's natural bottleneck.

We picked the map estate as in the last section where we have to defend the generator, there is a tight bottleneck that we can focus our firepower & explosives into.  (see the map below)

> **Key:**
>
> - 1) First Defending section
> - 2) Second Defending section
> - 3) Third (final) Defending section
> - Green Circle = proposed main defense area (bottleneck)
> - Orange Circle = Wretch flanking side

[image]

Sorry for the poor paint skills and small map picture (best I could find).  Each class that we can choose from has its different perks: **Medic** = Stim grenades (heals and revives), **Engineer** = Turret and repairs, **Scout** = Spot grenade that debuffs any attackers (they take more damage), and **Support** = Ammo grenades and Booshka (grenade launcher)

As mentioned before, we have tried multiple builds such as:

- 1 Medic, 1 Engineer, 1 Scout, 2 Support
- 1 Medic, 3 Engineers, 1 Scout
- 1 Medic, 3 Support, 1 Scout
- 1 Medic, 4 Support

**We were able to get to wave 9 with the 1 Medic, 4 Support build.  Our Methodology was this:**

> All support members spam booshka grenades into the bottleneck (Green circle on the map) while rotating ammo regen.  The Medic covers heals and the wretch flank (orange circle).  If anyone gets through ( ticker or wretch ) the medic would be the only person to run back to the generator.

**Our potential downfalls *IMHO:***

- The medic shouldn't be the one to leave us as it takes away our heals and coverage of the wretch flank.
- While we are getting ammo from our regen packs, we are all extremely close to each other, seceptable to a team wipe (everyone dying) by an explosion.

I am open to any ideas/methodologies/builds/etc to get this Onyx medal.

*Side note: I know the title of the question may appear subjective - but I am open to ideas for renaming the question.*

Answer (score 1):

Good tactic, seems to work most of the time when playing with skilled players. (At least till wave 7/8) But I would suggest a team of 1 Medic, 3 Soldiers and 1 Engineer.

Let the Engineer cover the Wretch side (I find that the Gnasher is way better at dealing with Wretches fast) and have the Medic support the Soldiers. The Engineer can drop a Sentinel when someone slips by or in case of a team wipe of the Soldiers. This way the Engineer can also, given the opportunity, try to fix any remaining fortifications.

(The Engineer could also be replaced by a Scout, the Debuff can be quite useful in the bottle-neck. But in this case I would recommend to use the Scout as support and then move the Medic to the Wretch side. The Scout can take care of the stragglers)